# "ImportError: No module named ..." for my own modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have written some Python modules, I get errors when import them in a Python script.

To be more specific, there is a directory called "affective_analysis", and it has two directories "emtiocon_parser", and "utility". In "emtiocon_parser" directory, which is my module there are **init**.py and so on files and in "utility" directory, there is a python scripts which imports emoticon_parser.

I import it as the following code:
from emoticon_parser.emoticoss import parse_emoticons

Following steps have been done:

1- In the corresponding directory of my own module (emtiocon_parser), there are `__init__.py` and `__init__.pyc` files.

2- I added the path of the module (emtiocon_parser) to sys.path by running `sys.path.append(..)`.

3- I put those paths in `PYTHONPATH` variable by means of the `export` command.

Still there is an error, I got the following error for one of them for example:

```
ImportError: No module named politeness.model
```

Python version is 2.7.10 and is running on Mac OS.

Comment: Okay. There's something strange. Did you named your files `init.py` as in the original post, or `__init__.py` as in the edit?

Comment: @JoshuaGrigonis: BTW, please don't change the meaning of a post in an edit, even in the slightest way. This can lead to a misunderstanding of the post. For example, you changed `init.py` with `__init__.py`. That could make a significant difference depending on whether Parastou mistyped the filename or not.

Comment: show your directory structure and which files it contains

Comment: __init__py, __init__.pyc, emoticoss.py, emoticoss.pyc

Comment: @ParastouTourani: Is it `init.py` or `__init__.py`?

Comment: @KemyLand second one with two underlines before and after init.

Comment: show the code so people know how you are attempting to import it.

Comment: And, more importantly, show the *whole* directory structure, and in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: @KemyLand these are the files in the module directory: __init__.py, __init__.pyc, emoticoss.py, emoticoss.pyc

Comment: @ParastouTourani: What do you mean by "module directory"? Show all the directories, subdirectories, files, and whatnot that have to do even the least with what you're doing. Do you have some sort of `project` or `python` or `whatever` parent directory? Then show that.

Comment: @KemyLand  there is a directory "affective_analysis", and it has two directories "emtiocon_parser", and "utility". In  "emtiocon_parser" directory, which is my modules there are __init__.py and so on files and in "utility" directory, there is a python scripts which imports emoticon_parser.

Comment: @KemyLand wondering the given information is enough or not.

Comment: @ParastouTourani: Yes, it is. Please update your question with that information.

Comment: Stackoverflow formats words surrounded by double underscores as __bold__ I didn't change the original question, only the highlighting.

Comment: Plz use `tree` command to generate the directory tree and show us real code that contains import lines if you really want to get it solved.